Can I reference to a composable function?
I can assign a composable function into a variable
    val a = @Composable { data: String -> Text("Team B: $data") }

However, if that composable function is a real function, how can I refer the variable to it?

@Composable
fun TeamBView(data: String) {
    Text("Team B: $data")
}


// this will error out stating 
// "Function References of @Composable functions are not currently supported"
val a = ::TeamBView 



Is there a way to work around it?

I work around it with

@Composable
fun TeamBView(data: String) {
    Text("Team B: $data")
}


val a = @Composable { data: String -> TeamBView(data = data) }


